# select values to update

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to input the last value from a select statement into an update. I've tried the query below but got the error: this gives me the error: missing right parenthesis.

```
update dt2112b2.postgraduate_order set order_total =
(select  item_cost  * order_quantity
FROM dt2112b2.order_stock, dt2112b2.postgraduate_order
WHERE dt2112b2.order_stock.menu_item = 
dt2112b2.postgraduate_order.menu_item and ROWNUM <=1
ORDER BY postgraduate_order.order_id desc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a correlated subquery.  You also have an issue with the `rownum` -- you are choosing an arbitrary row *before* the `order by`.  The `order by` does nothing.  Perhaps you really want the sum:

```
update dt2112b2.postgraduate_order po
    set order_total = (select sum(item_cost * order_quantity)
                       from dt2112b2.order_stock os
                       where os.menu_item = po.menu_item 
                      );
```

Or if you do want the matching order with the largest order id:

```
update dt2112b2.postgraduate_order po
    set order_total = (select max(item_cost * order_quantity) keep (dense_rank first order by order_id desc)
                       from dt2112b2.order_stock os
                       where os.menu_item = po.menu_item 
                      );
```